# maximum of modulus polynomial of degree $n$ in circle of radius 1

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials

Good time of day. Can you help me please with this task? Consider a polynomial of degree $n$ with leading coefficient equal to 1. Prove that the maximum of its modulus in a circle of radius 1 not less than one. When it is equal to one?

I tried to use Rouche's theorem. But it was unsuccessful. Thank you

Comment: See as well [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2777129)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1749037/42969.

Comment: In the given [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2777129), the solution found by the asker using Cauchy integral formula is remarkably simple !